# How Google Lighthouse check Speed index time

Tags: wordpress, optimization, seo, lighthouse

I am tuning the performance of a wordpress website.
So I use the Google Lighthouse, which is built in function of browser console, to check the score the website.

The homepage is an article page with default wordpress theme (`example.com`) score is :

```
First Contentful Paint : 3.0s
Speed Index : 3.1s
Large Contentful Paint: 3.1s
Time to Interactive: 4.0s
Total Blocking Time: 460ms
Cumulative Layout Shift: 0.002

Score: 75
```

To decrease the db query time, I try to save the result of html code and upload them to apache path `/var/www/html/static.html` .
Then, do the lighthouse test of `example.com/static.html`

```
First Contentful Paint : 3.0s -> same
Speed Index : 3.1s -> 10s
Large Contentful Paint: 3.1s -> 3.4s
Time to Interactive: 4.0s -> 3.4s
Total Blocking Time: 460ms -> 110ms
Cumulative Layout Shift: 0.002 -> same

score: 76
```

We can see the score is 1 point better, but the static page speed index time is 3x of the dynamic one.

I check the definition of Speed Index is `a page load performance metric that shows you how quickly the contents of a page are visibly populated.`

Is that mean the dynamic one will render a part of the theme before the databases query (visibly populated), and the static one included all the text and images link so the browser will not count visibly populated until all the content rendered ?

Or it just related to the browser / devices status (such as GPU, RAM usage or I/O time), so the time is not stable?

Is there any better solution can help me to increase the speed index time?